# How to solve $\dot{\mathbf{r}}(\theta)^2 + \mathbf{r}(\theta)^2 = 1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curves

I'm trying to determine all smooth functions $\mathbf{r}(\theta)$ such that the curve $\gamma(\theta) = (\mathbf{r}(\theta)\cos(\theta), \mathbf{r}(\theta)\sin(\theta))$ is unit-speed curve, i.e. that $\|\dot{\gamma}(\theta)\| = 1 \implies $$\dot{\mathbf{r}}(\theta)^2 + \mathbf{r}(\theta)^2 = 1$. According to my source, which omits intermediate steps, the solution ends up being $\pm\sin(\theta + \alpha)$ for some constant $\alpha$. But how can I show this myself?

Comment: Rearrange to get $\frac{\dot{r}(\theta)}{\sqrt{1 - r(\theta)^2}} = \pm 1$. Integrate both sides with respect to $\theta$.

Comment: Also, the provided solutions are not the only solutions. There are also solutions of the form $r(\theta) = \sin(\theta)$ if $\theta < \pi / 2$, and $1$ otherwise (and many other bizarre solutions which switch between being a $\sin$ solution and being constantly at 1). This difficulty comes from the fact that when $r = \pm 1$, the method of dividing by $\sqrt{1 - r(\theta)^2}$ obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that since $\alpha$ is constant, the solution can be written as

$$ \sin(\theta +\alpha)=C_1\cos(\theta)+C_2\sin(\theta)$$

for constants $A$ and $B$ using the angle addition formula.

---

Differentiating the ODE we obtain

$$2r'(\theta)(r''(\theta)+r(\theta))=0$$

So we have $r'(\theta)=0\implies r(\theta)=C$, and substituting into the equation we obtain $C=\pm 1$. Or we have

$$r''(\theta)+r(\theta)=0$$ and solving gives the solution $$r(\theta)=C_1\cos(\theta)+C_2\sin(\theta)$$

substituting into the ODE gives $C_1^2+C_2^2=1$, thus

$$r(\theta)=\pm \sin(\theta\pm\alpha)$$

for some constant $\alpha$.

Comment: How do you make the initial guess that $r(\theta) = C_1\cos(\theta) + C_2\sin(\theta)$?

Comment: There are many methods to find a general solution of a second order ODE with constant coefficients. Intuitively, you can ask :"what function gives the negation of itself when differentiated twice?". Or note that the characteristic equation is $m^2+1=0\implies m=\pm i,$ which gives the solutions $y_1=\cos(\theta)$ and $y_{2}=\sin(\theta)$. See [this](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/introsecondorder.aspx).